# How to FULLY change the color of the terminal prompt

Tags: command-line, bash, colors, ps1

I've changed `~/.bashrc` file of root and my own account.

The problem is (maybe because of my encypted home directory): when I log in to my normal account: **no color**, when I log in as root: **color**! But then no DIRECT access to encrypted directory.

Also when I log in to my normal account and type:

```
su no
```

(`no` is my normal account username) I get color!

Where is the other place that color gets set?

I use `PS1` all the time and change it based on what's happening in my system... Its very nice, but when i log in as my normal account I do NOT get color.

I'm currently executing a one liner command to search every file for `PS1=` (I'm sure my command is wrong, but whatever):

```
echo "$(find *)" | xargs grep PS1 | grep PS1
```

Correct command was:

```
echo "$(find *)" | xargs grep .* | grep PS1=
```

Comment: That one-liner is hideous, use `grep -R 'PS1=' ./`

Comment: Haha my first weeks on linux:) but i think Bash regular expressions are hideous ^.^

Answer (score 1):

```
cat /etc/bash.bashrc | grep PS1=

pico /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Edit the line you saw with first command.

My problem is that `.bashrc` was not working and apparently a default of `/etc/bash.bashrc` is used even prior authentication. Modifying this file solved my problem totally .

Comment: su -s /bin/sh no